# MissingArgumentException while configuring Flume

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng

I installed Flume

and tried to run this command

```
flume-ng agent -n $agent_name -c conf -f /home/gautham/Downloads/apache-flume-1.5.0.1-bin/conf/flume-conf.properties.template
```

and I get this exception

```
ERROR node.Application: A fatal error occurred while running. Exception follows.
org.apache.commons.cli.MissingArgumentException: Missing argument for option: n
    at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.processArgs(Parser.java:343)
    at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.processOption(Parser.java:393)
    at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.parse(Parser.java:199)
    at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.parse(Parser.java:85)
    at org.apache.flume.node.Application.main(Application.java:252)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are named your flume file with `.conf` extension.

And try to use the below command:

```
$ flume-ng agent \
--conf-file PathOfYourFlumeFile\
--name  agentameInFlumeFile\
--conf $FLUME_HOME/conf \
```

Change `$agent_name` with the name of agent you have used in your flume file.

You have to mention path of flume file with `.conf` extension instead of this `/home/gautham/Downloads/apache-flume-1.5.0.1-bin/conf/flume-conf.properties.template`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $agent_name use the actual name of the agent in your conf file.

I suspect that you do not have an $agent_name environment variable so it's being replaced with empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar issue. Later found out that by replacing all the hyphens(-) with hyphens again, it started working. Probably when i copied this command, the hyphens were replaced with minus(-) signs.